# VBA - How to click on a button in IE with no onclick attribute

Tags: javascript, html, vba, excel

I want to create a macro that do some automatic things on a specific website.
In the web I found many topics about clicking buttons in IE, but I did not meet the problem that I have.

I have the following html code on the website:

```
<a tabindex="0" class="x-btn-default-small" id="button-1028" role="button" aria-disabled="false" aria-hidden="false" hidefocus="on" unselectable="on" data-componentid="button-2018" data-qtip="Login">
```

and inside this attribute I have also a span attribute with the code:

```
<span class="x-btn-icon" id="button-1028-btnIconEl" role="presentation" data-ref="btnIconEl" unselectable="on" qa="btnIcon-loginButton"><span>
```

My problem is that I do not know how to click this button. Because I do not have any 'onclick' attribute in my html code. I hope that it is possible to click this button, but I have no idea how to do it.
I tried with the following code in VBA:

```
Set links = wwwIE.Document.getElementsByTagName("a")   
Dim n, m
n = links.Length
for m = 0 To n - 1
     If links(m).ID = "button-1028" Then
         links(m).Click
         links(m).onclick = True
         links(m).FireEvent ("onclick")
         links(m).FireEvent ("onchange")
         links(m).FireEvent ("onblur")
         links(m).parentElement.Click
     End If
Next m
```

But nothing works.

Comment: Is there an URL to share at all?

Comment: Note: If the link has an ID use `Set Element = Document.getElementById("button-1028")` so you don't need to loop through all the links and get the button by its ID directly.

Comment: This is an URL to this website: https://ecs.euclearing.theice.com/console/index.html?ts=0406035635230. And after putting login and password I want to click button to login

Comment: @JonasAl-Hadad well we cannot use the URL: "*ACCESS RESTRICTED*"

Comment: Which might mean Document.getElementById("button-1028").Click  ....

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Glad it is not just me!

Comment: I was afraid of it, because it is a stock market website. It is a first time when I encounter such problem. With 'onclick' attribute it is easy to click the button, but without it I completely do not know what I can do.

Comment: Well `wwwIE.Document.getElementById("button-1028").Click` should click that button.

Comment: But it does not. I think that if 'onlick' attribute is missing then I should use another technique to click the button.

Comment: @JonasAl-Hadad well, since the link has no "onclick" and no "href" I don't see how the link is working at all. So there is probably a JavaScript that handles all this. Might be cumbersome to figure that out, you might need to disassemble the whole site concept incl. JavaScripts to figure out how this is built up. If JavaScripts are minified this might get really hard.

Comment: I think you are right. JavaScript controls buttons in my case...